# How can I use of 2 format for 1 validation in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need a PDF format as well as an image format checking in only one validation

This is my code:

```
case 1:
        $r = $request->validate([
          'image0' => 'required|mimes:pdf|image',
        ]);
break;
```

But this only accepts PDF format, So how can I check for both PDF and Image?

Comment: I think you can write a custom validator which validates both.

Comment: Not sure about `image`, but how about `'required|mimes:pdf,jpg,jpeg,png,gif,bmp'`. Also why include `pdf` for image keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$r = $request->validate([
    'image0' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpeg,png,gif',
]);
```

Mimes are for file extension. So it checks if the uploaded file has the required extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can add image formats to `mimes`:

```
'image0' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpeg,bmp,png,gif',
```

See the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-mimetypes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use MIME type validation for check PDF format and image format

```
'image0' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,pdf',
```